# using ggvis view_static to export html file and dependencies

Tags: r, shiny-server, ggvis

I am using ggvis (0.4) to make a simple scatter plot, that I want to show on a website. I am using `view_static` to generate the html file. The [docs](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggvis/functions/print.ggvis) say I can set the `dest` parameter to specify the target directory for the html file and dependencies. However, no matter what I put there, I end up with the files in my tmp directory.

For example, if I do

```
library(ggvis)
test_plot <- mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>% layer_points()
view_static(test_plot, dest = tempfile(pattern = 'ggvis_test'))
```

I would expect my file to be something like `my/path/tmp/RtmpZw3qDp/ggvis_test7b3166824329/index.html`. Instead, it is `my/path/tmp/RtmpZw3qDp/viewhtml7b3166824329/index.html`, so did not adopt the pattern I specified.

Ideally, I would like to   say `view_static(test_plot, dest = tempfile(pattern = '~/target_dir'))` and find the output directory `target_dir` in my home directory.

Am I doing something wrong when calling `view_static`, or is there another way of exporting the html or embedding it somewhere?

EDIT - THERE IS A WORKAROUND

I have submitted an [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/350) on the github development site for ggvis - Winston Chang confirmed that the `dest` parameter is now deprecated. However as a workaround it was suggested one use `view_static` and `html_print` eg.

```
outfile <- mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>% view_static() %>% htmltools::html_print()
outfile
# [1] "/tmp/Rtmps5hgoi/viewhtml266b14fd08f8/index.html"
```

to get the location of the output file and then copy it to the target directory from there. Works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong. Here's the contents of `view_static`:

```
> ggvis::view_static
function (x, plot_id = rand_id("plot_"), dest = tempfile(pattern = "ggvis")) 
{
    spec <- as.vega(x, dynamic = FALSE)
    htmltools::browsable(ggvisLayout(plot_id, length(x$controls) > 
        0, spec, shiny = FALSE))
}
<environment: namespace:ggvis>
```

It doesn't seem to pass `dest` on to anything. (same hold true for the [dev version](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/blob/2652f7e31f2b820e19de6258349cfef5bdb1405d/R/print.R))